# How can I modify the Ubuntu Server install CD to add a hardware driver?

Tags: ubuntu, firmware, adaptec

I found this link to modify an Ubuntu install CD.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

However, I want to put the Adaptec aic94xx RAID driver onto the disk so that my RAID controller is recognised and I can set up a mirror.

How do I go about doing this?
Firmware file is:
http://kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jejb/aic94xx-seq.fw

EDIT:  decided to use a different RAID card.  The inbuilt one is too problematic to get going under Linux.  The 3Ware one just worked straight away no dramas.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu server are you using?  This page (http://www.adaptec.com/en-US/speed/scsi/linux/aic94xx-seq-30-1_tar_gz.htm) seems to indicate that the firmware is part of 2.6.19 and above.

Comment: I've just pulled a 3ware RAID card out of another server that wasn't being used.  Setup installed fine.  No problems at all.

Comment: @Zoredache - ubuntu server 9.10 32-bit.  I have it working on the 3ware card now.

Answer (score 1):

Besides making your own CD, you will also need to [recompile the kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile). I haven't done this in awhile so I'm not sure how much help that link will be, but most docs I have followed in the past have been fairly straight forward. If you need further help you might want to stick to the Ubuntu forums. Some of the followers on those forums are masters at this stuff.

Recompiling the kernel should also allow you to make a truly customized CD that should run pretty speedy, because you can take out modules you know you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to install this using the regular Ubuntu and alernate cd already right?  The Kernel for this install is generally full of drivers (modules) already these days...

Answer (score 0):

The driver itself is in the kernel, but the firmware it requires isn't in the initramfs on install CD -- at least in 9.10 and 10.04 releases.

This is tracked in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/315763